# itHow do I make div/ div images not move when resizing, while also allowing them to have a % from the top

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to resize the window while my divs keep their position on the page AND resize to a % of width and height I declare.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="view">
      <div class="Tree">          
          <img id="tree" src="img/tree.png">
      </div>
      <div class="Ground">
          <div class="g"></div>
      </div>      
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.Tree {
  position: absolute;
}
  .Tree #tree {
    position: relative;
    height: 75%;
    width: 75%;
    left: 30%; }

.Ground {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }
  .Ground .g {
    background-color: green;
    opacity: .5;
    position: relative;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%; }
```

The tree stays pretty constant, but when the window is the largest it can be on my macbook, it slides over to the left a little. The ground element vertically takes up half the page, I instead want it to only be placed 50% from the top. When I try to apply the 'top' style to either of them nothing happens. I know this is because the #tree is relative to .Tree and I don't declare a height/ width. I don't declare a h/w because it makes my #tree image's w/h off.

Thank you for the help!

Edit, added clarification:

I want the divs to resize according to the window width. I don't want them to change their left position. And I want to be able to set a 'top' % because I currently can't.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sqdgzbp6/

Notice on this website: anniwang.com that if you resize your entire window the drawings seem to also resize BUT they don't loose their position on the page. I want to recreate an effect similar to hers.

Comment: Please post a working code snippet and as well 2 images, clearly show what you have and what you want.

Comment: The code you have in your question doesn't match your fiddle, please update. I also don't understand what you want to achieve, so if you can make an image, or 2, I might be able to help.

Comment: @LGSon does the added clarification not help? If the viewers window width was 300px or 1500px the images would be in the same spot, but they also would be resized to either window width. (i.e. if i wanted my div to be 20% of the width of 300px window the div width would auto resize to 60px). But along with that I want to be able to set where the div is vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `.Tree` is an absolute positioned element, it need a height/width set explicit or else no child with percent will have anything to calculate their percent from, so in this sample I gave it a height and now `top` will work.

```css
.Tree {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#tree {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 60%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 20%;
}

.Ground {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.Ground .g {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: .5;
  position: relative;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="view">
  <div class="Tree">          
    <img id="tree" src="http://www.placehold.it/200/100">
  </div>
  <div class="Ground">
    <div class="g"></div>
  </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: Added fiddle, and tried what you said in it. As you can see if you remove the height 100% the tree will format to its correct w/h.

Comment: @user5812721 I updated my answer giving the `#tree` `height: auto; width: 200px;`. Now the `#tree` keeps its ratio and original size. When set to percent, as you did, it won't.

Comment: Close, but I want to the image to resize itself based on the window width instead of predefining a width

Comment: Still not exactly what i'm looking for. Notice on this website: http://anniwang.com/ that if you resize your entire window the drawings seem to also resize BUT they don't loose their position on the page. I want to recreate an effect similar to hers.

Comment: @user5812721 Looked at that page and when I resize the window, all figure's repositions/shrinks themselves according to the size of the window, just like my sample does, so as I can't see what you want, you either post a few images showing exactly what you want or I need to delete my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104751/discussion-between-user5812721-and-lgson).

Answer (score 1):

By the sound of it, you want divs to stop resizing when you've previously set a size of 50%. Remember this is only 50% of the window screen, so no matter how big or small the window, it will always scale to 50% of whatever you're viewing on. If you want it to be fixed, you could use `500px` that way it doesn't move because it's set to a fixed 500.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, sorry no, I want the divs to resize according to the window width. I don't want them to change their left position. And I want to be able to set a 'top' % because I currently can't.

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle with what you have then further explain what it is you need?

You don't want to set a percentage, you could just use something like

`position: absolute; top: 0; // this will put it directly at the top, then just increment the number the further down/up you want it to go. Yes the number is allowed to go minus.